# [amazon-data-pipeline]: can we not clone existing aws data pipeline from java sdk?

Tags: amazon-web-services, clone, amazon-data-pipeline

I want to clone my existing pipeline through code, and I just had quick walk through aws data pipeline document [here](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaSDK/latest/javadoc/index.html).

I couldnt find method to clone the existing pipeline in the SDK. Why is that?
Can somebody please answer?

Answer (score 0):

I think cloning a pipeline using SDK is not supported. They have a note about not supporting it through CLI on [cloning a pipeline](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/datapipeline/latest/DeveloperGuide/dp-manage-pipeline-clone-console.html) documentation:

> **Note**
>   You can't clone a pipeline using the command line interface (CLI).

I guess it should be the same for SDK as well.

I haven't tried this approach, but cloning an existing pipeline using SDK can be achieved as follows:

1. Create an empty pipeline using createPipeline.
2. Get pipeline definition of the existing pipeline that you want to clone using getPipelineDefinition.
3. Use the fields returned in Step 2 to populate the fields of a new PutPipelineDefinitionRequest object and call putPipelineDefinition with it.